# How to show which function grows faster?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Let $f(n) = 3^\frac{n}{2}$ and $g(n) = n^\sqrt{n}$.

One can easily see that for large $n$, both functions go towards $\infty$. So, one could use limit definitions for big $O$-Notation to calculate $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right)$.

However,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right) &= \lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{3^\frac{n}{2}}{n^\sqrt{n}}\right) \\
  &= \lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\frac{3^\frac{n}{2}}{1} * \frac{1}{n^\sqrt{n}}\right) \\
  &= \lim_{x\to \infty} (\infty * 0) \\
&= \mathord{?}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\label{eq2}$$

Maybe I am missing something trivial but I don't know how to continue from here on out. Perhaps there is another way to solve this problem? Only looking for tips and not solutions!

Comment: Using logarithms, you can express $g(n) = 3^{\sqrt{n} \log_{3}(n)}$. Does that help?

Comment: It's not correct to write that the limit is $\lim_{x \to \infty}(\infty \cdot 0)$. Because $3^{n/2}$ increases without bound, and $\frac{1}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}$ tends to zero, we are dealing with what is known as an 'indeterminate form', where simply considering the terms individually doesn't work. $f(n) \to \infty$, and $g(n) \to \infty$, but which one is growing faster? That's something that has to be worked out by comparing the rate of growth of $f(n)$ with $g(n)$, rather than considering these functions by themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would compare their log's.  $\ln f(n)$ is linear.  $\ln g(x) = \sqrt{n} \ln n << \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n} = n$.  So $f$ is bigger than $g$ by a good bit.